# Is there any c++ IDE checking coding style as Pycharm does?

Tags: c++, ide, pycharm

Pycharm has a very nice feature to check coding style according to PEP8 conventions. It's good for python beginners to write decent code from the very beginning. I am wondering if there's any c++ IDE implementing similar features, for instance, checking google c++ coding style?

Comment: jetbrains also has a C++ IDE - CLion, it is a cross platfrom C++ IDE, however not official released, it has coding style check . http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Roadmap+for+CLion+1.0 you can try the EAP version

Comment: C++ is a far more complicated language than python, used for a wider range of applications, and what's considered good style on the basis of extensive hands-on experience in one problem domain may be considered awful in another type of program or environment.  Many of the choices are largely arbitrary (e.g. camel vs. lower-case-with-underscores identifiers, leading `m_` vs trailing `_` for member variables, indentation sizes, brace placement, and it's generally considered that consistency with your own programming environment is the dominant factor in selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

When google released their c++ coding style, they also provide a python script named cpplint for style checking.

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/

If you can embed this script into your IDE, you can employ it to do code style checking.

There is an article that explains how to integrate cpplint into Visual Studio 2012 (guess also applicable to other versions).

http://sww-it.ru/2015-01-14/1199

Comment: A more generic tool would be clang-format -- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html . The --style flag has default options for various open source projects (LLVM, WebKit, Mozilla, Chromium, as well as google), or a style file that defines the various formatting options. Some of the things that it doesn't take care of are naming rules. It's great for indenting/breaking lines/keeping spaces in the right place in function/control statements. clang-tidy can also be useful.

Comment: A plugin for CLion exists to integrate `cpplint` into the IDE: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7871